# flask_socketio connected to client, but not receiving messages

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a Flask server-app/React client-app into which I am trying to integrate flask_socketio. I have replicated the standard introductory example from the flask_socketio docs and it works fine with my React front-end.

However, when I try to replicate the results in flask, using the exact same steps I cannot send or receive messages. I can see a client has connected in the output when I run my flask app, and in the browser console I have a console.log telling me I am connected to the server, but emit (or send) don't seem to work the way the intro example did.

I have eventlet installed, and the docs say that flask_socketio should recognize this automatically. Here are some code snippets for reference.

app/socket/__ init __.py

```py
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = SocketIO(cors_allowed_origins='http://localhost:3000')
```

app/socket/socket.py

```py
from flask_cors import cross_origin
from flask_socketio import send, emit

from . import socketio

@cross_origin
@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connection():
    print('a user has connected')
    emit('mymessage', 'Hi client, I am server.') # I've tried `send` here too

@cross_origin
@socketio.on('mymessage')
def handle_message(message):
    print('Message from client: ' + message)
```

app/__ init __.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

from .socket import socketio


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Cross Origin Resource Sharing
    CORS(app)

    # Socket.IO
    socketio.init_app(app)


    return (socketio, app)
```

app/app.py

```py
from . import create_app

socketio, app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000)
    #app.run("0.0.0.0", port=5000, threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
```

React component

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

class Figures extends React.Component {

  setSocketListeners () {

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected to socket');
      socket.emit('mymessage', 'Hi server, I am client.');
    })

    socket.on('mymessage', function(data) {
      console.log('Message from server: ' + data)
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setSocketListeners()
  }

...
```

Output:

terminal

```py
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 216-814-307
(4089) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2019 02:40:35] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MoEsrSZ&sid=a4f73c34553f478cabde2f919b48fe98 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.002675
(4089) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 36512)
(4089) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 36514)
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2019 02:40:36] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MoEsrSf&sid=a4f73c34553f478cabde2f919b48fe98 HTTP/1.1" 200 235 1.612156
```

browser

```
connected to socket
```

EDIT:

Preliminary debugging seems to suggest this is some issue with 'create_app()'. See [link](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/731) from @miguelgrinberg. Still no progress on how to fix the issue though.

Have enabled `socketio.init_app(app, async_mode="eventlet", engineio_logger=True)` and disabled debugging in flask to make sure werkzeug isn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was related [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/716)

I think you should enable transport mode to WebSocket when opening socket on your frontend code, something like:

```
    const socket = io('http://localhost:5000', {transports: [websocket]});
```

Also you need to install gevent and gevent-websocket and import socket.io-client like:

```
    import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
```

I've implemented a working example: https://github.com/roj4s/webicami

Comment: Github: 404. Could you public your sample project again?